# google play services онлайн таблица рекордов

Tags: java, android

Как подключить oнлайн таблицу рекордов GooglePlay Services в приложение?

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Comment: крутоооооооооооо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Настроить консоль разработчика для Google Play Game Services, чтобы получить ресурсы вида:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Google Play game services IDs.
Save this file as res/values/games-ids.xml in your project.
-->
<resources>
  <string name="app_id">310266082735</string>
  <string name="achievement_take_10_levels">HgkIr62KmoQJEAIQBg</string>
  <string name="achievement_take_30_levels">HgkIr62KmoQJEAIQBw</string>
  ..................
</resources>`

`app_id` – идентификатор приложения, строки вида `leaderboard_xxx` и `achievement_xxx` указывают на конкретную таблицу рекордов и достижение соответственно.

2. Создать ресурсный xml-файл с именем `games-ids.xml` в android-проекте своей игры и поместить туда ресурсы выше.
3. Установить с помощью `Android SDK` следующее: `Google Play Services`, `Google Repository` и импортнуть библиотеку `google-play-services_lib` в проект.
4. Импортировать библиотеку класса `GameHelper` в проект. Скачать [BasicGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils).
5. В файл манифеста добавить:
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Мета дата внутри тега `application` :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

6. В `MainActivity`:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication 
   implements GameHelperListener, ActionResolver
   ```

Интерфейс `GameHelperListener`:

```
public interface GameHelperListener {
    /**
     * Вызывается при неудачной попытке входа. В этом методе можно показать
     * пользователю кнопку «Sign-in» для ручного входа
     */
    void onSignInFailed();

    /** Вызывается при удачной попытке входа */
    void onSignInSucceeded();
}
```

Создать Интерфейс `ActionResolver`:

```
public interface ActionResolver {
    /** Узнать статус входа пользователя */
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS();

    /** Вход */
    public void loginGPGS();

    /** Отправить результат в таблицу рекордов */
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score);

    /**
     * Разблокировать достижение
     * 
     * @param achievementId
     *            ID достижения. Берется из файла games-ids.xml
     */
    public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId);

    /** Показать Activity с таблицей рекордов */
    public void getLeaderboardGPGS();

    /** Показать Activity с достижениями */
    public void getAchievementsGPGS();
}
```

7. Пример кода `MainActivity`:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements
   GameHelperListener, ActionResolver {
   // помощник для работы с игровыми сервисами
   private GameHelper gameHelper;
   // класс нашей игры
   private TestGame game;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // CLIENT_ALL указывет на использование API всех клиентов
   gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
   // выключить автоматический вход при запуске игры
   gameHelper.setConnectOnStart(false);
   gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
   // запретить отключение экрана без использования дополнительных
   // разрешений (меньше разрешений – больше доверие к приложению)
   getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
   // Входной параметр this является ActionResolver. Позволяет вызывать из
   // игрового цикла платформо-зависимые методы GPGS
   game = new TestGame(this);
   AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
   initialize(game, config);
   gameHelper.setup(this);

   }

   // методы gameHelper’а: onStart(), onStop() вызываются для корректной работы
   // GPGS в жизненном цикле android-приложения

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   gameHelper.onStart(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       gameHelper.onStop();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();

   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   // здесь gameHelper принимает решение о подключении, переподключении или
   // отключении от игровых сервисов, в зависимости от кода результата
   // Activity
   gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }

       @Override
       public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
           // статус подключения
           return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
       }

       @Override
       public void loginGPGS() {
           try {
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   // инициировать вход пользователя. Может быть вызван диалог
                   // входа. Выполняется в UI-потоке
                   gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
               }
           });
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
       // отправить игровые очки в конкретную таблицу рекордов с ID
       // “HgkIr62KmoQJEAIQAQ”
       Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(),
           "HgkIr62KmoQJEAIQAQ", score);

   }

       @Override
      public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
           // открыть достижение с ID achievementId
          Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementId);
       }

   @Override
   public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
       // вызвать Activity для всех зарегистрированных таблиц рекордов. Так же
       // можно вызывать Activity под конкретную таблицу
       startActivityForResult(
           Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(gameHelper
                   .getApiClient()), 100);

   }

   @Override
   public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
       // вызвать Activity с достижениями
       startActivityForResult(
           Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper
                   .getApiClient()), 101);

   }

   @Override
   public void onSignInSucceeded() {
   }

   @Override
   public void onSignInFailed() {
   }

   }
   ```
8. Для таблицы рекордов вызвать `submitScoreGPGS(int score)` интерфейса `ActionResolver`.

Comment: А как вызвать таблицу рекордов с переменной формата float?